# Traversing dependency graph in StructureMap

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, structuremap

I can't find any mechanism to traverse dependency graph in StructureMap.
My problem is as follows:

Class `Coordinator` has two dependencies: `ServiceA` and `ServiceB`.
Both `ServiceA` and `ServiceB` have one dependency: `CustomWebClient`.
`CustomWebClient` has one dependency: `Logger`.

I have to inject different implementations of `Logger` into `CustomWebClient`. It depends whether `CustomWebClient` is injected into `ServiceA` or `ServiceB`.

The only conditional mechanism I found is based on the parent type and root type, but it doesn't help in my case. Is it possible to configure this in StructureMap?

Comment: Should be able to create a new `CustomWebClientB` that derives from `CustomWebClient` that depends on `LoggerB`? Then conditionally use that if `ParentType` is `ServiceB`.

Comment: Thanks but I really don't want to do that. The real situation is more complex and I simplified it to express the essence of the problem. In our project there's like 6 types of Services. Besides that, the `CustomWebClient` has couple of decorators. I want to avoid creating 18 more classes.

Comment: Yea, that changes things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I didn't find any way to do that in a normal way, I found that StructureMap stores the dependency stack internally.

In **StructureMap 2.6.4.0** we can use build stack frames:

```
container.For<Logger>().AlwaysUnique().Use(ctx =>
{
    var pi = typeof (BuildFrame).GetProperty("Parent", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public);
    var frame = ctx.BuildStack.Parent;

    while (frame != null)
    {
        var currentType = frame.ConcreteType;

        if (currentType == typeof(ServiceA))
            return new LoggerA();
        if (currentType == typeof(ServiceB))
            return new LoggerB();

        frame = (BuildFrame)pi.GetValue(frame, null);
    }

    return new LoggerDefault();
}
```

In **StructureMap 3.1.2.0** we have to use `_instances` private field of `BuildSession` object (`IContext` implementation). `_instances` field has the following type: `Stack<Instance>`.